# Specific strings as possible Arguments - Enums?

Tags: c#, string, enums, arguments

for a tool that I am writing I need a "random text" generator. I want to allow the user to be able to choose from premade strings like these:

```
const string baseCollection = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const string numbers = "0123456789";
const string specialChars = "°^!\"§$%&/{([)]=}?\\`´*+~'#,;.:-_><|";
const string germanAddition = "ÄÖÜäöü";
const string frenchAddition = "éàèùâêîôûäëïüçœ«»";
const string russianAddition = " бвгджзклмнпрстфхцчшщйаэыуояеёюиьъ";
```

Which in terms should be used to run this method.

```
public string RanText(int length, ???)
{
    string charCollectionString = "";
    foreach(string str in charCollectionStrings) {
        charCollectionString += str;
    }

    //stuff

    return finalString;
}
```

I have thought of using an Enum but those do not allow Strings. What would be the **cleanest** way of creating a range of possible arguments?

Comment: Enums seem to be the answer here. What's your problem with them? Do you want the caller to be able to pass in multiple choices? e.g. `baseCollection` AND `numbers`

Comment: You could write an `if else` block checking which options they chose, and then concatenate a string within each block. `else if(choice4) { masterString += germanAddition }`, and then pass that string to your `RanText`method as your `charCollectionString`.

Comment: @Sweeper YES! Thats exactly what I want. E.g: User creates: new TestHelper() -> Calls TestHelper.RanText(15, baseCollection, german) for a Random text with both charsets

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) out.

Comment: I have already seen the possibility of using an Enum with an IfElse or a Switch but wouldn't that be extremely messy over time? Like imagine some day there will be 30+ possible charsets.. There must be a cleaner way (i hope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a `Dictionary<>`? For example:

```
public enum CType
{
    Base,
    Numbers,
    Special,
    German,
    French,
    Russian
}

public readonly Dictionary<CType, string> Collections = new Dictionary<CType, string>
{
    { CType.Base, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" },
    { CType.Numbers, "0123456789" },
    { CType.Special, "°^!\"§$%&/{([)]=}?\\`´*+~'#,;.:-_><|" },
    { CType.German, "ÄÖÜäöü" },
    { CType.French, "éàèùâêîôûäëïüçœ" },
    { CType.Russian, "бвгджзклмнпрстфхцчшщйаэыуояеёюиьъ" }
};

public string RanText(int length, CType[] parameters)
{
    string charCollectionString = "";
    foreach (CType param in parameters)
    {
        charCollectionString += Collections[param];
    }
}
```

Then:

```
RanText(1, new[] { CType.Base, CType.Numbers, CType.Russian });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I never used Dictionarys. Can I make one of the Parameters of my RanText method use an entry. Like: public string RanText(int length, params anyEntryFromThisDict)

Comment: Dictionaries aren't needed at all here. The `enum` values are sequential ints, starting from `0`. This could easily be a `string[6]` array, or `List<string>`, with the enum value used as the index

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, I'm only using the Dictionary for clarity